# what does this element do?

Tags: css

What is the meaning of the following element in HTML...

```
margin:0 0 0 847px  **!important;**  margin:0 0 0 848px..
```

Is it related to the browsers???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this particular order is that Internet Explorer did not interpret `!important` up to version 6. Thus, the second margin instruction applies to Internet Explorer <= 6 only.

This is called a browser hack. A good overview on browser hacks is [here](http://ajaxian.com/archives/css-browser-hacks).

Comment: thanks for the answer but somewhere in the web sites I find that the next part of the above style specified after !important is meant for the entire IE .. such as this link...
http://www.evolt.org/ten-css-tricks-you-may-not-know

Answer (score 3):

CSS rules marked `!important` take precedence over later rules.
So in your case, the first, the first `margin` definition will be considered, i.e. `0 0 0 847px`.

Answer (score 2):

That's not HTML.  That's something called CSS.  It tells your browser how to format HTML.  For example, this CSS is setting the margins around a certain element to be 847 pixels on one side.

Comment: Dave, I accidentally edited your answer when I wanted to edit mine. I rolled it back. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It's CSS, not HTML.

The `!important` means that the HTML element that the CSS applies to should have a left-margin of 847 pixels and this should *not* be overridden by later styles. It which case the `848px` following is ignored.